# iOS: UIButton setSelected

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Right now, I'm using this code:

```
[btn setTitle:@"disabled" forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; 
[btn setTitle:@"selected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

How can I let it show the text of "selected"? I found it does not always work when I use

`[btn setSelected:YES];`.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you creating this button in a view with  storyboard or a nib file or are your creating it programmatically?

Comment: ...this code should work fine, but if you are using a storyboard/nib file then make sure you have the method which sets [btn setSelected:YES] connected to your button as an IBACTION so when the user clicks the button it sets the state as SELECTED.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work fine for the simple case where you either have the button selected (and not highlighted nor disabled) or you have it disabled (and not highlighted nor selected).

Keep in mind that some control states can overlap. if you do not specify images for the overlapped states, the UIControl has to pick one. I'm not sure on the exact algorithm for this, but I'd guess a priorities list and UIControlStateSelected is lower in priorities than UIControlStateDisabled